# GUI is not possible on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I understand the GUI (such as those powered by tkinter) does not work on Google Colab, any alternatives at this point?

Error message

> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in google's colab

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Good question, at this point want to have an easy way to get a UI to input Python code into. Does that make sense?

Comment: You mean like:

    `eval(input('python code goes here: '))` ?

Comment: Exactly and in a nice visual way, do you think I should just build an HTML page and plug in script? Is that an option? What do you recommend?

Comment: Hard to make a recommendation without much more detail about what it is you're trying to accomplish (not just the microtask of "execute python code" but the bigger-picture goals you have).

Answer (score 0):

To use these notebooks you need to install binary MoebInv libraries and their dependencies.

In short, you simply need to execute it in CoLab or your Ubuntu-18.04 desktop the next cell